# Merge/Group data in SAS

Tags: sas, db2, proc-sql

I have the following dataset

| Id | com | typ | cust | bu | tar | item | item_sufx | part | line | dtn_cd | geo_con | sign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ZL-UK-23 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 2 | 1 | ZL-US-22 | - |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 3 | 1 | ZL-JP-22 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 4 | 2 | ZL-US-44 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 5 | 2 | ZL-US-66 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 2 | 1 | 1 | AP-TN-44 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 2 | 2 | 2 | AP-TN-22 | - |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 3 | 1 | 3 | PQ-AR-44 | + |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 3 | 2 | 4 | PQ-AR-22 | - |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 1 | 1 | DE-NN-44 | + |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 2 | 2 | DE-NN-22 | - |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 1 | 3 | HK-DC-44 | - |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 2 | 4 | HK-DC-22 | + |

I want the following output

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't work properly

```
data table_A;
set table_A;
merge
table_A (where= (DCTN_CD = '1') rename=(GEO_CON=FROM_GEO))
table_A (where= (DCTN_CD = '2') rename=(GEO_CON=TO_GEO))
table_A (where= (DCTN_CD = '3') rename=(GEO_CON=BETWEEN_GEO))
table_A (where= (DCTN_CD = '4') rename=(GEO_CON=AMONGST_GEO))
run;
```

Any idea how do that? I am open to SAS or PROC SQL (DB2) suggestions.

Comment: Work properly? What didn't work? You should have only the MERGE statement not the SET statement as well by the way. Your sample data shows the variable name as DTN_CD or is DRCTN_CD not shown?

Comment: oh drctn_cd and dctn_cd are the same. What didn't work was that I couldn't get separate rows for between_geo nd amongst_geo when dctn_cd = 3 and 4..they come on the same row as when dctn_cd = 1 or 2. Also can you see my desired output picture?

Comment: You don't have a BY statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compute two synthetic values:

- line_group, for the case of multiple line groups within a part, and
- dtn seq, to enforce original ordering.

Then you can merge by the line_group and dtn_seq.

Example:

```
data have;
input
Id  com$ typ cust  bu  tar item  item_sufx part  line  dtn_cd$ geo_con$ sign$ group; format _numeric_ 4.;
datalines;
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 1 1 1 ZL-UK-23  +  1
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 1 2 1 ZL-US-22  -  2
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 1 3 1 ZL-JP-22  +  3
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 1 4 2 ZL-US-44  +  1
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 1 5 2 ZL-US-66  +  2
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 2 1 1 AP-TN-44  +  4
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 2 2 2 AP-TN-22  -  4
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 3 1 3 PQ-AR-44  +  5
10  ARF 3 2585  12  100 4587  800 3 2 4 PQ-AR-22  -  5
50  PFP 3 3000  12  100 9999  899 1 1 1 DE-NN-44  +  6
50  PFP 3 3000  12  100 9999  899 1 2 2 DE-NN-22  -  6
50  PFP 3 3000  12  100 9999  899 1 1 3 HK-DC-44  -  7
50  PFP 3 3000  12  100 9999  899 1 2 4 HK-DC-22  +  7
;

data have_grouped;
  set have;
  by id com typ cust bu tar item item_sufx part dtn_cd;
  
  line_decreased = line < lag(line) ;
  
  if first.part or line_decreased then line_group+1;
  if first.dtn_cd then dtn_seq=1; else dtn_seq+1;
run;

data want;
  set have_grouped;
  merge
    have_grouped (where= (DTN_CD = '1') rename=(GEO_CON=FROM_GEO SIGN=SIGN_FROM))
    have_grouped (where= (DTN_CD = '2') rename=(GEO_CON=TO_GEO   SIGN=SIGN_TO))
    have_grouped (where= (DTN_CD = '3') rename=(GEO_CON=BETWEEN_GEO SIGN=SIGN_BTWN))
    have_grouped (where= (DTN_CD = '4') rename=(GEO_CON=AMONGST_GEO SIGN=SIGN_AMNG))
  ;
  by line_group dtn_seq;
run;
```

You could get an ERROR about data not in order (because where= is not **required** to deliver rows in any particular order).  If that happens you will need to merge four sorted views that do deliver the data in the line_group dtn_seq order.

Comment: In the part where if first.dtn_cd then dtn_seq=1; else dtn_seq+1; If I want to restart the dtn_seq when dtn_cd changes from 1 to 2 then how can I do that?

Comment: The group column I added demonstrates the expectation I inferred from your output picture.  `first.dtn_cd`, is the trigger for restarting the dtn_seq within the specificied `BY` group -- so it's already happening. `first.`<variable> (and `last.`<variable>) are automatic pseudo-variables having a binary flag value indicating sequence state within a by group.

Comment: That works. I needed to add in the dtc_cd in the grouping to work. However, as you predicted, I did get the ERROR of data not in order. What do you mean when you say " merge four sorted views that do deliver the data in the line_group dtn_seq order."? What are the 4 sorted views?

Comment: I have a variant to my question here. I have multiple ID and Com values in the same item_sufx value which is causing error in the code given here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268474/sas-data-set-setting-variables-of-data-set-to-add-line-numbers