# SAS Data Set Setting Variables of data set to add line numbers

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have the following dataset

| Id | com | typ | cust | bu | tar | item | item_sufx | part | line | dtn_cd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 22 | XYZ | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 22 | XYZ | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 22 | XYZ | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | ARF | 3 | 2585 | 12 | 100 | 4587 | 800 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 50 | PFP | 3 | 3000 | 12 | 100 | 9999 | 899 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

I want the following output

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't work properly

```
data table_A_mod;
set table_A;
by Id com typ cust bu tar item item_sufx part dtn_cd;
line_decreased = line_nbr < lag(line_nbr);
if first.part 
or line_decreased
then line_group+1;
if first.dtn_cd then drctn_seq=1; else drctn_seq+1;
run;
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.Table_A.
```

I tried many combinations of "by" for the variables but nothing worked.

I have built up on my previous question here stackoverflow.com/questions/77100373/merge-group-data-in-sas but the difference between the two is in the current question I have different ID and Com values in the same item_sufx group. This is why my code isn't working.

Any idea how do that? I am open to SAS or PROC SQL (DB2) suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried sorting it in the desired order first?

Comment: Isn't the order already correct in ascending order? Actually more than the order I am interested in the grouping of (Id com typ cust bu tar item item_sufx part dtn_cd) and that to be grouped together in one line_group (The line_group number can be in any order but the columns mentioned here should be grouped together)

Comment: I have built up on my previous question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100373/merge-group-data-in-sas
but the difference between the two is in the current question I have different ID and Com values in the same item_sufx group. This is why my code isn't working.

Comment: What variable contribute to the grouping?  You seem to only care about ID and LINE, so why did you list the other ones on the BY statement?  But your example data is NOT sorted by ID.  Should we sort it first?  Or do you want to correct the example data?

Comment: I do care about all the variables mentioned in the BY statement. They are the columns by which I want to group and generate the line_group column. The reason I mentioned ID (and com) column is because that changes within the item_sufx group = 800..
I have based my solution based on this question I had asked earlier
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100373/merge-group-data-in-sas
In the earlier question my ID and Com column were same for the item_sufx=800 but here they change..rest all is same..

Also updated the required output.

Comment: Your data as presented is NOT sorted by those variables.  And if ask SAS to check the groups created by those variables by adding the NOTSORTED keyword to the BY statement most of the observations belong to groups with only one observation.  Please explain what you are doing as your description is not matching the data. For example if you want to group the data by ID then why is the data not sorted by ID?

Comment: If I sort the data by those variables and just try to calculate your new grouping variable (what your picture calls LINE_GROUP) then there are 6 groups not the 5 in your picture because the PFP group has line numbers in 1,2,1,2 so those last four observations are two groups not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data sorted then sort it.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by Id com typ cust bu tar item item_sufx part dtn_cd;
run;

data want ;
  set have;
  by Id com typ cust bu tar item item_sufx part dtn_cd;
  if first.id or line<lag(line) then group+1;
run;
```

Result

```
                                                        item_
Obs    id    com    typ    cust    bu    tar    item     sufx    part    line    dtn_cd    group

  1    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       1        1        1
  2    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       2        1        1
  3    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       3        2        1
  4    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       2       1        1        2
  5    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       2       2        2        2
  6    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       3       1        3        3
  7    10    ARF     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       3       2        4        3
  8    22    XYZ     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       1        1        4
  9    22    XYZ     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       2        2        4
 10    22    XYZ     3     2585    12    100    4587     800       1       3        2        4
 11    50    PFP     3     3000    12    100    9999     899       1       1        1        5
 12    50    PFP     3     3000    12    100    9999     899       1       2        2        5
 13    50    PFP     3     3000    12    100    9999     899       1       1        3        6
 14    50    PFP     3     3000    12    100    9999     899       1       2        4        6
```